# "itemize" with customized bullets

Tags: lists, itemize

```
\begin{itemize}

\item blah blah blah blah

\end{itemize}
```

As far as I know the main difference between the code above and just writing something like

```
$\bullet$ blah blah blah blah
```

is that everything within the "item" gets indented to a point to the right of the bullet.

I'd like to do that with customized bullets instead of just bullets, one of which would look like `{\bf Q:}` and another like `{\bf A:}`.

That way when typing a multi-line paragraph after `{\bf Q:}` or `{\bf A:}`, the subsequent lines would be vertically aligned with the first one.

How can that be done?

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem} \begin{itemize}[label=\textbf{Q:}]...\end{itemize}`?

Comment: Not related to the question, but `\bf` is an obsolete command that shouldn't be used in modern documents. You should use `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: related: ["Q" and "A" in margin - out of alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58352)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to define a customized list; in the following example, the `mylist` environment is such that \item will produce as label `Q:` bold-faced; the newcommand \itema can be used to produce the label `A:` bold-faced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbf{Q:}}
\newcommand\itema{\item[\textbf{A:}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item \lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\itema \lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, not requiring packages, is to define two commands using the optional argument for `\item` to produce the desired labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\itema{\item[\textbf{A:}]}
\newcommand\itemq{\item[\textbf{Q:}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\itemq \lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\itema \lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```