# Erroneous vertical spacing in tabular in combination with makeindex

Tags: indexing, tabularx

I'm having some trouble with vertical whitespace appearing in a `tabularx` environment where  I really don't expect it to. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeindex % removing this line also removes the 

\newcommand{\loc}[1]{\index{#1@\emph{#1} (location)}\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
  foo \\
  \hline
  \loc{bar} \\
  \hline
  baz \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

And now for something completely different:

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
  \hline
  foo \\
  \hline
  \loc{bar} \\
  \hline
  baz \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The two tables have the same body. For some reasons, there's a vertical gap in the second table:

[image: problem]

The space disappears if I comment out the `\makeindex` command, but obviously that's not an option in my real-life document. Where does the space come from, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularx` has nothing to do with this; even

```
xxx\parbox[t]{5cm}{\loc{bar} blah}
```

would present the same problem, with “*bar*” one line below “xxx”.

The problem is starting the parbox with a “whatsit”. Add `\leavevmode`, that will not do anything harmful in other situations:

```
\newcommand{\loc}[1]{\leavevmode\index{#1@\emph{#1} (location)}\emph{#1}}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeindex % removing this line also removes the 

\newcommand{\loc}[1]{\leavevmode\index{#1@\emph{#1} (location)}\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}

xxx\parbox[t]{5cm}{\loc{bar} blah}

\begin{tabular}{|p{10cm}|}
  \hline
  foo \\
  \hline
  \loc{bar} \\
  \hline
  baz \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

And now for something completely different:

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
  \hline
  foo \\
  \hline
  \loc{bar} \\
  \hline
  baz \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is a "whatsit"?

Comment: @vwegert A “whatsit” is an item TeX places in its internal lists for special purposes (writing to auxiliary files, color changing, and others); it's a kind of “to do” note, because the actual job will be performed later. Because of how `\parbox` is implemented, a whatsit at the very beginning causes an empty box to be set and the paragraph will start below this box. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58378/4427